# Nginx Phusion Passenger Ruby: Don't send app log to nginx log

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I'm running Nginx and Passenger to host a Ruby on Rails app.  By default, the app logs quite a bit, and it goes to the dedicated app log.

However, with Passenger and Nginx, *all* of the app's log are copied to the nginx log as well! I believe this may happen because the app emits logs to stdout or stderr.

This drowns the Nginx log, which I really only want to cover http and nginx activity, not everything that goes on internally to the app.

**How can I tell Passenger and Nginx to *not* forward the app's log (or stdout or stderr) to the Nginx log?**

---

### Update

This question hasn't received any responses (other than "don't use Passenger").  If something is unclear or missing, please post.  And, if this is simply impossible, please post that as well.

Comment: My first thought would be: don't use passenger.

Comment: Passenger is needed to provide an HTTP interface to the app.

Comment: Eh? You can use any Ruby web server such as thin or puma.

Comment: Okay, but, for many reasons, we're using Passenger, and I don't want to replace the entire thing.  It works well.  I just want to clean up the logs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with the `passenger_app_log_file` directive, but the bad news is that it is a paid Passenger Enterprise option. See here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_app_log_file

I'm slightly amused that Passenger takes over `stdout` then charges you to get it back.